# How to access calling context "this" in Typescript callback when "this" is defined in callback signature

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I am using an api (d3.js) that defines a callback as:

```
on(typenames: "tick" | "end" | string): ((this: Simulation<NodeDatum, LinkDatum>) => void) | undefined;
```

My code is as follows (irrelevant code removed):

```
class DiagramBuilder
{
  private force: d3Force.Simulation<d3Force.SimulationNodeDatum, undefined>;
  private importantVariable: string = "need this";

  void registerStuff()
  {
    this.force = d3Force
      .forceSimulation();
    force.
      .on("tick", this.tick);
  }
  
  tick() {
   // Here I need to access this.importantVariable
  }
}
```

Within the callback, "this" is an instance of type `Simulation<NodeDatum, LinkDatum>`, but I need to access the parent of type `DiagramBuilder` in the callback to get to `importantVariable`.

I am aware of three solutions:

1. Use `bind()`
2. Create a static singleton instance of `DiagramBuilder`
3. Register the handler as

```
 force.
      .on("tick", () => this.tick(this));
```

and change tick to

```
tick(builder: DiagramBuilder)
{ 
  // use builder.importantVariable
}
```

But then I would have to pass the `DiagramBuilder` instance into all references to `tick()`.

Surely there is a cleaner way than any of these solutions?

Comment: For 3. why would you need to change the signature? Or pass in a `this` to the method.  If you use `.on("tick", () => this.tick());` then the `this` inside `tick` would be the same `this` that *around* `force.on` which in turn should be a `DiagramBuilder`. Unless you call `registerStuff` by divorcing it from its `this` value. But if you have `diagramBuilderInstance.registerStuff()` then inside it `force.on("tick", () => this.tick));` it would work.

Comment: Thanls @VLAZ that does work - although then I can't access the original `this` of type `Simulation<NodeDatum, LinkDatum>` within `tick()`.  But it does answer the original question, cheers.

Comment: You can't do this with either of your suggestions, as well. Since `this` can only have one value, you can choose which one it would be. If you use a regular function, then the `this` inside would be `Simulation` but not the surrounding `DiagramBuilder`. If you really need both, then you'd have to change `tick`  to accept `Simulation` as parameter; then alias `const self = this` before adding the handler with `on`; then do  `force.on("tick", function() { self.tick(this) });` so you both call `tick` with the correct `this` inside and also have access to `Simulation`.

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ.  Surely this is a flaw in the design of the language?  Maybe API authors shouldn't pass `this` in their callbacks, to avoid the need for  these hacky workarounds.

Comment: Technically a feature. A late-bound `this` allows for far less memory consumption, otherwise each function would have to carry its own `this`, therefore sharing the same method between multiple instances would require more than one copy per instance. With that said, the name `this` seems to be the biggest problem to me. It *doesn't* work the same as other compiled languages like Java where `this` doesn't change. If anything, `this` is just a parameter to every function and if not explicitly passed in, it gets implicitly resolved at call time. This is unintuitive and the mechanics of the

Comment: whole thing obscure. It's probably one of the biggest problems the language has by hiding what's happening. You can always explicitly pass in `this` by doing `fn.call(thisValue, param1, param2)` which does actually do a good job of showing `this` is just a parameter. But when calling the function directly `this` is set  to whatever was before the last `.`: `a.b.f()` -> `this = a.b`; a.f()` -> `this = a`; `f()` -> `this = undefined`